# Why is new used to access the constructor of a class?

Tags: java, class, constructor, new-operator

I came across a piece of code as follows:

```
  final static Map<String, Supplier<Shape>> map = new HashMap<>();
  map.put("CIRCLE", Circle::new);
```

Where `Circle` is a class. I guess here `new` is used to access the constructor of the class `Circle`. How can `new` be used like this? What is this technique called? I could not find any documentation.

Comment: It's sintactic sugar, see if the answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20001427/double-colon-operator-in-java-8) help.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [New object instantiation when using Java 8 streams](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31763930/new-object-instantiation-when-using-java-8-streams)

Answer (score 0):

This a reference to a constructor. You can pass that where a matching functional interface is expected. Look here for more info http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java/lambda-expressions.html#constructor-references